# React, fecting data with redux but data is not displaying

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I'm working on a news website using react, redux toolkit, node for the backend and MongoDb for the database. When the user clicks on the navbar it navigates to the page and using redux toolkit, I fetch the list of articles from the DB. But when the page loads the articles object is empty and I can't display the articles.

```
//This is the articles page:
const ArticlesPage = (props) => {
  const articles = useSelector((state) => state.GetArticles.articles);
  const loading = useSelector((state) => state.GetArticles.isLoading);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { tags } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchArticleByTag(tags));
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      {articles ? (
        articles.map((article, index) => (
          <>
         
            <ArticleThumbnail key={index} thumbnail={article} />
          </>
        ))
      ) : (
        <>loading</>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ArticlesPage;
```

```
//THis is the action that calls the DB:

export const fetchArticleByTag = (tag) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(
        ` http://localhost:8080/api/v1/articles/${tag}`
      );
  

      return response.data;
    };

    try {
      const articleData = await fetchData();
     
      dispatch(ArticleSlice.actions.Articles(articleData));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
};
```

I tried using Conditional Rendering to check if the article object is empty. I was expecting once the value is saved in the Redux store the useEffect would cause the page to re-render. But it still empty. The implementation I had worked on other page

Comment: I guess that the action that is supposed to set the data is not setting it

Comment: Using `redux-toolkit` but not using `createAsyncThunk`? We need to see a more complete [mcve] that includes where & how `ArticlesPage` is rendered so we can see what the `props.tags` value is, and the redux code we we can see how state updates are handled and selected.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. @Konrad you were right about the action not setting the data. But the problem was with how I sent the data with the backend. It works now.